# Beat Brick as Lilith

Tags: borderlands

I recently bought this game with my friend and we really enjoy duels, however I can't find way to beat him. What would be the best way and build to use against Brick? His berserk seems to be unstoppable with mass HP. I'm focusing on SMGs with my character(Lilth), though we're both on level 18, so it may change on higher levels.

Comment: Duels in Borderlands were always an aftertought and are incredibly imbalanced in both games. But are you using Phasewalk? Also high-damage single hit weapons are often the best/cheapest way to win.

Comment: @BenBrocka Ofcourse I use:). But his berserk lasts so long and gives him invincibility:P. Well, I'll try to defeat him on higher levels.

Comment: Do you have enough points to get Daze on bullets yet? That could slow him down a lot but I think it's a higher-level skill.

Comment: @BenBrocka Not yet, but that's what I thought about - slowing him down. By the way, can I slow him when his berserking ?

Comment: I would assume so, but I never dueled with a Brick. Also I don't think he's technically invincible, his health regen might just be overcoming your SMG's DPS, a heavier weapon might be more noticable.
If all else fails, you might just make a gentleman's agreement not to use any action skills whatsoever; that makes duels much more balanced.

Comment: @BenBrocka Well... I will try. Thanks for help anyway.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplistically speaking, you'd defeat him if you had better gear and Dazed him (and stayed away from his [Berserk](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Berserk)ing). [Siren](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Lilith) PvP builds do not need to change per class faced; (of the two best PvP COMs) the build is your preference for how you wish to fight.

I was about to answer this question with advice for a [Berserker](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Brick) (Brick). Beat a Berserker as Lilith (the Siren)? Excuse me, but ha! It's usually the other classes that seek advice to defeat the Siren. It's about time I wrote something like this for the Siren. [Edit: I forgot I already [did](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60807/borderlands-lilith-skill-builds/115803#115803).] Where do I even start? I'm going to write as a general PvP guide for Sirens.

**Dazing**
"I know there are a lot of people who think daze is OP in pvp. Which is true[.]["](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=1751939&postcount=1)
Luckily, the Siren has three ways to Daze (for days). But wait, what is Dazing?

> [Dazed](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Status_Effects#Dazed) enemies behave normally, but suffer greatly slowed movement speed and reduced accuracy. The effect further extends to any weapons used by the Dazed foe, reducing the rate of fire of even fully automatic weapons, and slowing projectile velocity.
>
> - Lilith can daze enemies with melee strikes, her action skill, or gunfire.
>
>   - Striking
>   - Dramatic Entrance
>   - Mind Games
> - Brick can daze enemies with melee strikes.
>
>   - Bash

So, particularly if your Berserker opponent is smart enough to [Sting like a Bee](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sting_Like_a_Bee), do your best to keep your distance from him (until you wish to land Striking or Dramatic Entrance).
With [Mind Games](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_Games), the higher the [rate of fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116214/46216), the better (keeping accuracy constant of course). [Dramatic Entrance](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Dramatic_Entrance) doesn't always land at point blank. [Striking](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Striking) can make up for that.

**[Silent Resolve](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Resolve)**
King ([damage resistance](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Resolve#Notes)).

**[High Velocity](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/High_Velocity)**
Get this skill, at least when you get to the point where a player is downed in less than a second.

**[Phasewalk](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Phasewalk)**
[Soldier](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Roland)'s got [Scorpio Turret](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpio_Turret), [Hunter](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mordecai)'s got [Bloodwing](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodwing), Berserker's got Berserk, what do you got? Phasewalk, baby! Elemental explosions on entrance and exit, enhanced speed, invisibility, invincibility, surround sound, high defini—ahem.  Want to Daze? Pop it. Health low? Pop it. To close the gap? Pop it. Others can hear your footsteps and the ambient noise, so end it fast to reduce the time they get to pinpoint you or end it late after crawling (crouched) around (to silence foot-falls) so that, even though they can tell you're nearby, your final position is unknown.

https://www.youtube.com/v/AcmpjIfb0OQ&autoplay=1&start=19&end=21 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/113632/46216

**[Radiance](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Radiance)**
Do not get this skill. "[I]t gives away your position in Phasewalk. I don't think that Radiance even damages other players in PvP[."](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115803/46216)

**[Phase Strike](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_Strike) & [Venom](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Venom)**
Don't get these either. Ever.

> [A]t the upper levels/end-game...
>   Mêlée is negligible. This is a case of [linear mêlée damage, quadratic bang bang](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LinearWarriorsQuadraticWizards). Although mêlée damage may not necessarily scale linearly, it's still bringing a knife to a gun-fight. At the upper levels, you should only use your mêlée attack offensively if you know the enemy's health is low enough that it will finish them off and you need to reload. Or it's a single enemy, but with a lot of health, and you've got Bash, so you want to Daze them to mitigate their damage output."

**[Slayer](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Slayer)**
There are no critical hits in PvP.

**On-kill skills**
At best, you get lucky somehow or you [kite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18903/46216) or have a car handy that you destroy right before duelling.

**Mercenary [COM](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Class_Mod_%28Borderlands%29#Siren)**
[Anarchy](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Anarchy_%28SMG%29) or ([Double](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=110429)) [Stinger](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Stinger_%28Borderlands%29).
[Gasher](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Gasher)? [Wildcat](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Wildcat)? **[Tsunami](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Tsunami)**? https://www.youtube.com/v/qH5X_YtP5RU%26autoplay=1%26start=555%26end=557

**Tempest [COM](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Class_Mod_%28Borderlands%29#Siren)** (with +84% Shock Chance Resistance & +4 [Silent Resolve](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Resolve))
Use with [S&S](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/S%26S_Munitions) [Orion](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Orion), [shock](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shock) S&S [Thanatos](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Thanatos), shock [Redemption](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Redemption), or [Undertaker](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Undertaker), (or [burst-fire](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Destructor) [rocket launchers](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Rocket_Launcher) (not so much in [arena](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Arena))).
You should be using shock [grenade mods](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Grenade_Mod) regardless.

"[One](http://youtu.be/TH_6yAUtMDg)-[shot](http://youtu.be/63Qk6GMjCQ0)[."](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116069/46216)

I've dabbled in Defender and Catalyst COMs. Defender COM was probably either to sandbag or get kills via grenade mod. Catalyst COM is for extended and/or consecutive rounds, for more Phasewalk, which is very important. Switch to it after a hit-and-run to recharge Phasewalk faster. Plaguebearer COM for [Inner Glow](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Inner_Glow).

**[Element](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Elemental_Damage)**
"Shock is the king element in PvP. This is because a player's total hit-points are mostly composed of shield[."](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116180/46216)
"In PvP, you should always be using a shock artifact. Fire is lowest tier element because it does the least damage against shields[."](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115803/46216)

You can also study up on your opponent's [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116069/46216).